# How to mock an HTTP call triggered on ApplicationReadyEvent

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, e2e-testing, wiremock

I am trying to use Wiremock to intercept an HTTP call fired on `ApplicationReadyEvent`. The issue is that this call is made before a Wiremock rules being applied. So this API is no mocked.

See following example

```
public class OnApplicationReadyListener implements  ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>{

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    // in this pathe is being send a request
    consulHealthCheckService.register();
}
```

}

The stubbing is configured in `@Before` phase, which is actually triggered once a Servlet container is ready. So actually - *after the HTTP call is fired*

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = ConsulApplication.class)
    public class ConsulApplicationTest {

        @Rule
        public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(Agent.DEFAULT_PORT );

        @Before
        public void setup(){
            // is being executed after the http call was fired
stubFor(get(anyUrl()).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())));
            stubFor(put(urlEqualTo("/agent/service/register"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                            .withHeader("Content-Type", APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                            ));
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldRegisterServiceOnApplicationStartup(){ 

            verify( putRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/agent/service/register")));


        }
    }
```

Is there any way how to stub given http call? Please note: Iam not able to mock the service code which actually triggers the call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `WireMockRule`, you could statically create a `WireMockServer` start it on the port, and load the mappings even before this test class is fully initialized.  IF this does work, you could ensure the server is shutdown in an `@AfterClass` method.

If you try that and it's still making the request before your test class is initialized, then you'll have to figure out when/where that request is made and find another way to test your assertion as it's being fired before the test class is even initialized.